# Laptop screen not detected when closed/docked - Manjaro, kernel 5.10

Tags: manjaro, xrandr, laptop, monitors

I have a HP Elitebook 840 G5, and am using the Ultraslim docking station with it.  If I boot the laptop on its own, not connected to the dock, all is fine.  I can dock and undock without a problem.

If I reboot/power on the laptop docked to the station with the lid closed, the laptop display (eDP1) has no modes associated with it, and you cannot switch on the display using xrandr or undock the laptop.  I am using the Intel driver, but have tried the modesetting driver as well, with largely the same results.

I have also tried kernel 5.4 and 5.9 along with 5.10.

When started when docked, xrandr outputs the following for the laptop display -

```
Output eDP1 is not disconnected but has no modes.
```

I have tried creating the necessary 10-monitor.conf section in xorg with the following (gathered from the Xorg modeset output of a live cd, since Xorg on Manjaro does not output this) -

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "eDP1"
    Modeline "1920x1080_120.1" 280.00  1920 1944 1992 2120  1080 1090 1095 1100 -hsync -vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_120.1"
EndSection
```

And this has not helped, and even with this, if you try and activate the display, xrandr fails with -

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

I can also see this message in dmesg when booting docked -

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
```

That doesn't come up when undocked.

The xorg.0.log file, on boot when undocked/open does show that EDID loads the specifications for the laptop screen correctly, but does not do so when docked/closed.  I have tried to use the get-edid application, but it always fails -

```
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!
Attempting to use the classical VBE interface

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

    VBE version 0
    VBE string at 0x0 "O"

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Report DDC capabilities

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

Reading next EDID block

VBE/DDC service about to be called
    Read EDID

    Performing real mode VBE call
    Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f15 bx=0x1 cx=0x0
    Function unsupported
    Call failed

The EDID data should not be trusted as the VBE call failed
Error: output block unchanged
```

The lid state is recorded correctly, so it does know if its open or closed.  While starting the laptop open and undocked is a workaround, surely there must be a way to get this to correctly detect the laptop screen so it can be undocked if started docked?

I have looked at the kernel module options for the i915 driver to see if there is something there that might help, but nothing really struck me as being useful.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've been testing with an older Elitebook 820 G1, on the same HP Ultraslim docking station, also on Manjaro (kernel 5.10), and have found that if I boot this laptop with the screen closed on the dock, the internal screen is detected and it can be undocked as expected.

Comment: xrandr correctly sees the modes, I can see in the Xorg log that EDID information is being read correctly and is using the same "intel" driver (xf86-video-intel) and not the modesetting driver.  This indicates it is a hardware/driver problem on the later laptop/newer GPU (Intel HD Graphics 620).  Is that a reasonable assumption?